# ui:table immediately disappears after retrieving data

Tags: jsf, wildfly, jsf-1.2, wildfly-9

We are moving our existing JSF 1.1 project (currently running in Glassfish) to WildFly 9 and JSF 1.2. Most of the components in our JSPs are **ui:** type components (from http://www.sun.com/web/ui).

We are able to deploy and run the application. All other components apart from `<ui:table>` are loading properly. But whenever a page displays a table, it immediately disappears. The table with proper data is visible for a very short time (milliseconds).

All the related managed beans have not been modified for this migration and are request scoped. Following is an example of a table we are using.

```
<ui:table binding="#{admin$ViewActiveUser.tblActiveUser}" 
    clearSortButton = "true"
    deselectMultipleButton = "true"
    id = "tblActiveUser"
    paginateButton = "true"
    paginationControls = "true"
    selectMultipleButton = "true"
    width = "825">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out line 268 (`table.hidden = "hidden";`) of javascript file **table.js** in the **defaulttheme.jar**. Path to the javascript file inside the jar is */com/sun/rave/web/ui/defaulttheme/javascript/table.js*